# How to add div field dynamically in to a html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-append

i tried to add a div field dynamically on clicking button but i am not getting response. here is my code.

```html
<div id="#para">
  <tr class="divider"></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Medicin Name" style="width:80%;height:30px;"></td>
    <td><input type="file" </td>
    <td><input type="time" placeholder="Enter Medicin Time"></td>
    <td><input type="date" placeholder="Enter Start Date"></td>
    <td><input type="date" placeholder="Enter End Date"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="divider"></tr>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="button" id="#btn1" value="Submit"><img src="images/plus.png"> Add More Notification</button>
```

Here Is My Js Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#para").append('  <tr class="divider"></tr> <tr class="notification-row"><td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Medicin Name" style="width:80%;height:30px;"></td>  <td><input type="file" </td> <td><input type="time" placeholder="Enter Medicin Time"></td> <td><input type="date" placeholder="Enter Start Date"></td><td><input type="date" placeholder="Enter End Date"></td> </tr><tr class="divider"></tr>');
  });
});
```

Comment: did your console showing any eror?

Comment: no there is no error

Comment: Your html isn't valid. You can't use `tr` in `div`. Maybe problem is here.

Comment: stil not working @Mohammad

Comment: You changed `div` to `table` and it didn't worded?

Comment: i remove tr and td tags

Comment: updated code is >

Comment: <div id="#para1">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Medicin Name" style="width:80%;height:30px;">
                                              <input type="file"> 
                                              <input type="time" placeholder="Enter Medicin Time">
             <input type="date" placeholder="Enter Start Date">
             <input type="date" placeholder="Enter End Date">
                                           
           </div>
           <button  class="button" id="#btn2" ><img src="images/plus.png"> Add More Notification</button>

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#para1").append('  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Medicin Name" style="width:80%;height:30px;"><input type="file"> <input type="time" placeholder="Enter Medicin Time"><input type="date" placeholder="Enter Start Date"><input type="date" placeholder="Enter End Date">');
    });
});
</script>

Comment: Also remove `#` from `id` attributes of html. Then it should work. https://jsfiddle.net/w03bahLt/

Comment: @Mohammad, i think i have posted the answer haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div id="para">
  <tr class="divider"></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Medicin Name" style="width:80%;height:30px;"></td>
    <td><input type="file" </td>
    <td><input type="time" placeholder="Enter Medicin Time"></td>
    <td><input type="date" placeholder="Enter Start Date"></td>
    <td><input type="date" placeholder="Enter End Date"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="divider"></tr>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="button" id="btn1" value="Submit"><img src="images/plus.png"> Add More Notification</button>
```

you should delete # on your HTML script

> in HTML (id) = jQuery (#)
>   in HTML (class) = jQuery (.)

you can source this on google

Comment: kindly tick it as your answer if you found it was correct.. Thanks @AmitChauhan